# Creating new AppDomain instances inside a Windows service doesn't work

Tags: c#, service, concurrency, windows-services, appdomain

I am trying to create a Windows service with C# which spawns multiple processes inside it.
For this I am using AppDomain functionality and creating multiple of them at startup in the OnStart method of my service:

```
    public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceBase()
        {
            InitializeComponents();
        }
    
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
            setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetMyExePath());
            var ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain NEW", null, setup);
            var t = new Thread(() => {
                    ad.ExecuteAssembly(GetMyExePath());
                    AppDomain.Unload(ad);
                });
            t.Start();
        }
    }
```

(I know I should put a check to prevent recursively starting new domains from each new one, but for now it doesn't even start the first one)

When I try the same in a Console Application, it works fine.
But when I build it as a Windows Service and run it from the service manager, it seems to terminate after startup.

Opening the Event Viewer, I see this about my service:

"Service can not be started. An instance of the service is already running."

Running it without the app domain creation code works just fine. It fails to start even a single domain as it seems to view them as trying to start the same process twice instead making a new domain within the process.

Is there a way to get this to run on services or does it only work for regular applications?

Comment: Are you aware that the newer versions of .NET (Core, 5 & 6) don't support AppDomains? If so, I'd question why you're writing new code that's immediately going to be an upgrade burden.

Comment: What does the code for `GetMyExePath()` do? It might be miscalculating the path for an installed service vs. running as an executable. Try adding some logging to your service and see what it logs when you try and start it and it fails.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes I know, however we are using .NET Framework with no plans to upgrade the project to Core yet. If there is an alternative to the domains I would use it, as I desperately need such a feature right now.

Comment: @MartinCostello it returns the executable path it internally calls Assembly,GetEntryAssembly().Location, I have verified it is correct, using the debugger with the same code in a regular console application,

Comment: Since the recommendation for newer .NET versions is to use Processes rather than AppDomains, and Processes have been around forever, I don't see why you wouldn't be working with Processes now.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wouldn't this run into the same issue? Trying to start a process that is already running (the current service)

Comment: Windows services are single-instance, you canot start more than one. it's impossible 2 instances of the same service to run.